# Multiple plots having xticklabels syncronized with xticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to know if it is possible to synchronize xticks with xticklabels, in this way:

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

XLabels = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U']
```

Now on screen 0 5 10 15 20, but on second subplot, there is A B C D E.

I want to see: A F K P U.

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, FormatStrFormatter, MultipleLocator   # format X scale
    import numpy as np
    x=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
    ax1.plot((np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0)), 'b-')
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)  # , sharex=ax1)
    ax2.plot((np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0)), 'r-')
    #plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
    ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%0d'))
    ax2.set_xticklabels(['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U'], fontsize=12)
    plt.show()
```

[image: Result of run]

How can synchronize, so that I have A F K P U corresponding with 0 5 10 15 20 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest option is to set the ticks and ticklabels manually. E.g. if you want to tick every `N`th integer, you can choose a subset of the lists (`[::N]`) to set the ticks and labels to.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
XLabels = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q',
           'R','S','T','U']

N = 5

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.plot((np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0)), 'b-')
ax1.set_xticks(x[::N])

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)  # , sharex=ax1)
ax2.plot((np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0)), 'r-')

ax2.set_xticks(x[::N])
ax2.set_xticklabels(XLabels[::N], fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

In order to kind of automate this, you can use a `FuncFormatter`, which selects the correct letter from the `XLabels` list according to the tick's location.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, FuncFormatter, MultipleLocator
import numpy as np

x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
XLabels = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q',
           'R','S','T','U']

N = 5

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.plot((np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0)), 'b-')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(N))

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)  # , sharex=ax1)
ax2.plot((np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0)), 'r-')

def f(c,pos):
    if int(c) in x:
        d = dict(zip(x,XLabels))
        return d[int(c)]
    else:
        return ""

ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(N))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(f))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Automate is the best solution for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the list of labels to get the ones matching the x axis, and use `set_xticks` and `set_xticklabels`

A simplified example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
labels = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U']

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax1.plot(x, x, 'b-')

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
ax2.plot(x, x, 'r-')
ax2.set_xticks(x)
ax2.set_xticklabels([label for index, label in enumerate(labels) if index in x])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Ok, but the solution is not general enough for my problem. Thank you.

Comment: @popad I think you would benefit from stating what you mean by "not general enough". I would consider both answers given so far as valid solution to the problem from the question. If you need something else, critically reread your question to make sure this requirement is actually stated somewhere, if not, edit the question.

Comment: I say "not general enough", because this solution modify initial x.